# Which of the following is the incorrect solution in finding the limit of $\frac{x^2}{x-y}$ as ${(x,y) \to (0,0)}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have been solving the limits of functions of two variables to review for my upcoming test.

I have two solutions with different answers. I am trying to review both solutions, but it seems both have no errors.

I tried to solve the

$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2}{x - y}$

Here are my solutions.

Solution 1:
Parameterization the equation $f(x,y) = \frac{x^2}{x-y}$ by $x(t)$ and $y(t)$

Let $k$ be a real number such that

$\frac{1}{k}=\frac{x^2}{x-y}$
Therefore, the said equation can be parameterized as
$
\left\{
  \begin{array}{lr} 
      x(t)=t  \\
      y(t)=t-kt^2  
      \end{array}
\right.
$

This follows that

$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2}{x - y}$

$ = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{t^2}{t-(t-kt^2)}$

$ = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{t^2}{kt^2}$

$=\frac{1}{k} = 
\left\{
  \begin{array}{lr} 
      1&if&k=1  \\
      -1&if&k=-1  
      \end{array}
\right.
$

Therefore, the limit does not exist.

Solution 2:

Parameterization the equation $f(x,y) = \frac{x^2}{x-y}$ by $x = r \cos(k)$ and $y = r \sin(k)$.

$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2}{x - y}$

$ = \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{r \cos^2(k)}{[2\cos(k)+\sin(k)]}$

$=0$

Therefore, the limit is equal to 0.

My next question is when is the right time to parameterize the function in terms of $x = t$ and in terms of $x = r\cos(k)$ , $y = r\sin(k)$?

Please feel free to share your feedback about my two solutions.

Answer (score 1):

In Solution 2 you cannot treat $k$ as a constant (independent of $r$). By doing so you are looking only  at radial limits, i.e limits along lines approaching $(0,0)$.